# Extracting two different files to two a two different folder in a single batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch script,

```
 unzip.bat with two arguments destination and source zip file.
```

calling that batch by passing arguments in another batch.

```
echo %~1
if exist "G:\tett\ITG" (
@RD /S /Q "G:\tett\ITG"
 )  
if exist "G:\tett\pylib" (

 @RD /S /Q "G:\tett\pylib"
)



unzip.bat "G:\tett\" "G:\test\test.zip"

unzip.bat "G:\tett\" "G:\test\pylib.zip"
```

I could see the last line is not executing pls help. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `CALL unzip.bat "G:\tett\" "G:\test\test.zip"`

Comment: @JosefZ Please, post as an answer. This is a recurring question, but your answer may help others, right?

Answer (score 0):

The following, *basic script with no validation*, should do that:

```bat
@Echo Off
For %%A In ("ITG","pylib") Do If Exist "G:\tett\%%~A\" RD/S/Q "G:\tett\%%~A"
For %%A In ("test","pylib"
) Do If Exist "G:\test\%%~A.zip" Call "unzip.bat" "G:\tett\" "G:\test\%%~A.zip"
```

*From `Call/?` "Calls one batch program from another."*